# How to deploy the .Net Compact Framework and SQL Server Compact Edition with the Application

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-mobile

I have a windows mobile 6 application.For Application installation,Device require sql server ce and .net framework to run Application on the device...If a device has these Prerequisited Softwares already...the application will work.

If a device has no these Prerequisited Softwares [Sql server ce or dotnet framework to run the App] it wont work. So i need to install this also at the time of Application installation along  with the cab.

How to Pack these Preqrequist Softwares with the cab file????

Or Any Other Solution to this...please help me on this...

I have added an image as i have in my application as of now....

[image: Here is the settings currently i have on my application...]

Comment: I Got second Query in the above image,i m getting the Resource's value while directly giving like this  "Properties.Resources.VersionNo" Now....Thnk you...

Answer (score 0):

The best way to try to include *SqlServer CE* and your *.NET Framework* files in your project is to mark your **Application** Project so that it includes all dependencies and include those files in your **Setup** Project.

That said, sometimes the installs work and sometimes they require a lot of debugging to make them work.

[image: Screenshot of a WM5 Project]

Comment: Thnx for ur answer...Sir,By doing as above,is the cab installer check for the existence of sql server ce and .net CF  in the device..?  if those are installed,simply skip this from installation and continue with Application installation only...otherwise install these softwares and proceed with Application installation ....i just want to confirm it...